# how can i put 2 links in one tab of bottstrap nav?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I tried to put 2 links in 1 tab but wasn't really successful here i is my navbar code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <title>{% block title %} welcome to music stories{% endblock %}</title>

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show'>
            <button type= 'btn' class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss='alert'></button>
            <p>{{user.username}}, welcome to music stories world</p>
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show">
            <button type="btn" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss='alert'></button>
            <a href="{% url 'users:login' %}" class="alert-link">Log In</a>
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    <a href="pages:home">Home</a>
    <nav class="navbar text-dark bg-warning container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a  class='nav-link active' href="#">{{user.username}}</a><br>
                    <a class="nav-link" href=" {% url 'user:logout' ">Log Out</a>
                </li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class='nav-link active' href="{% url 'login' %}"> Log In</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:signup'%}">Sign Up</a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
            `<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle='dropdown' href="tags">tags</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="nav-item" href="#">tag1</a></li>
                    <li><a class='nav-item' href="#">tag2</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-item" href="#">tag3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">communication</a></li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'pages:musiclist' %}">music list</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class='nav-link' href="{% url 'pages:music_create' %}">add</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i wanted to put both username and logout both in 1 tab or login and logout ,how can i put 2 link in 1 tab to act like 1 tab?
i had a second question that is not related to topic but can i override `.container` of `<body>` in `<nav>`.

Answer (score 2):

based on what I understood from your explanation is that you can use a DROPDOWN that contains username and logout (check this [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/dropdowns/#overview)).

about overriding the container class, the better solution is to add a class, with a different name like; container-main, in your css file with what you wish to be like and add it to you div.

Comment: oh thanks this was really useful, may i ask one more question pls?

Comment: Specifically within a tab: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navs-tabs/#tabs-with-dropdowns